# WLAN 802.11 - Is SIFS, DIFS, AIFS or nothing used before beacon frame is sent?

Tags: beacon, wifi

Is SIFS, DIFS, AIFS or nothing used before beacon frame is sent?

I got the frame duration in us by adding 192 us preample and data_bits/1Mbps together but I don't know if I should add DIFS SIFS etc to get total airtime that is required to send one beacon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am not totally clear about what you are trying to ask.There are so many parameters regarding airtime for any 802.11 frame.**

You mentioned 192us that [Long preamble] is time taken to send PHY layer header of 802.11 Beacon frame.

And Beacon frame is kept in Highest Priority queue in AP and uses the same CSMA/CA method to gain access to wireless medium.I am not sure about which  IFS time AP uses before sending beacon.I will get back to you on this.

Update:
--Please ignore my comment.I was not allowed to edit :P --

After discussing with Experienced WLAN Developer,this is the best information i got.
There is no special facilities are given for Beacon.This means, to send Beacon AP has to content the Wireless medium as usual.But beacon is given higher priority than other TX packets ,present in Queue.Thats why you will notice there will be delay [ from actual TBTT ] in Beacon Timestamps [As medium was busy so AP could not able to send Beacon in TBTT]. But STAs will be synchronized according to TimeStamp in Beacon.

Comment: Sending data frame: DIFS + CW + preample + S(data_bits/datarate). S() is rounding up to integer number of symbol times. Sending Ack: SIFS +preample + S(data_bits/datarate). I'm trying to fugure out that what happens when sending beacon frame.

Comment: After discussing with Experienced WLAN Developer,this is the best i got.

Answer (score 0):

Before transmitting a Beacon APs shall use DIFS.

Beacons follow the same channel access procedure that data frames (See IEEE 802.11-2016, Section 11.1.3.2), this is, the AP shall perform a backoff and wait for the channel to be idle during DIFS before sending the Beacon.

Beacons shall be scheduled at the nominal beacon interval, that's why they shall be prioritised (as mentioned by @Bamdeb), but again, they must follow the regular IEEE 802.11 channel access procedure and wait for DIFS.